PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true
I'm working on a project where I need to calculate TF-IDF scores for news articles stored in a MongoDB collection. I've implemented a MongoDB aggregation pipeline to perform this calculation, but I'm encountering an error that says "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort." I believe this error is related to the size of the dataset or the complexity of the aggregation pipeline.

    // Step 2: Tokenization
    function tokenize(text) {
      // Simple example using regular expression
      return text.toLowerCase().match(/\b\w+\b/g);
    }

    // Step 3: Inverted Index
    const newsCollection = await database.collection("something");

    // Step 5: Ranking Algorithm (Simple TF-IDF)
    async function calculateTFIDF(newsCollection) {
      const cachedScores = await redis_server.get('tfidf_scores');
      if (cachedScores) {
        return JSON.parse(cachedScores); // Parse cached scores from Redis
      }
          // Aggregate pipeline to calculate TF-IDF scores
      const tfidfResults = await newsCollection.aggregate([
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            title: 1,
            author: 1,
            // tags: 1,
            summary: 1,
            tokens: { $split: ["$content", " "] },
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$tokens"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              _id: "$_id",
              token: "$tokens",
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            tokens: {
              $push: {
                token: "$_id.token",
                count: "$count",
              },
            },
            docCount: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            tokens: 1,
            tfidf: {
              $map: {
                input: "$tokens",
                as: "token",
                in: {
                  token: "$$token.token",
                  tfidf: {
                    $cond: {
                      if: { $eq: ["$docCount", 0] },  // Check for empty docCount
                      then: 0,  // Assign 0 if docCount is 0
                      else: {
                        $multiply: [
                          "$$token.count",  // TF
                          {
                            $ln: {
                              value: { $add: ["$docCount", 1] },  // Add 1 to docCount
                              base: Math.E
                            }
                          } / {
                            // ... (IDF calculation)
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            tokens: 1,
            tfidf: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$tfidf",
                initialValue: [],
                in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this.tfidf"]] }  // Access tfidf value
              }
            }
          }
        }
        // ... further calculations or adjustments based on your requirements
      ], { allowDiskUse: true }).toArray();
      await redis_server.setEx('tfidf_scores', 3600, JSON.stringify(tfidfResults)); // Set with expiration
    return tfidfResults;
    }

    // Usage example
    const tfidResults = await calculateTFIDF(newsCollection);

    // await newsCollection.createIndex({ title: 'text', content: 'text', headline: 'text', author: 'text' })
    await newsCollection.createIndex(
      {
        title: 'text',
        content: 'text',
        headline: 'text',
        author: 'text',
      },
      {
        weights: {
          title: 5,
          content: 2,
          headline: 4,
          author: 3,
        },
      }
    );
    
    // Step 6: Query Processing
    async function search(query) {
      const searchResults = await newsCollection.find({
        $text: { $search: query },
      }, {
        projection: {
          _id: 1,
          imageUrls: 1,
          headline: 1,
          summary: 1,
          time: 1,
          author: 1,
          views: 1,
          score: { $meta: "textScore" }, // Access TF-IDF score from $meta
        },
      }).sort({ score: -1 }).toArray();
      return searchResults;
    }


    let news_list = []
    const searchResults = await search(text);
    console.log("searchResults",searchResults)

What I've Tried:

Created indexes on relevant fields to improve query performance.

Used the allowDiskUse: true option in the aggregation pipeline to allow MongoDB to use temporary files on disk.


MongoDB version: 7.0.9
Dataset size: 1458 Documents
